# Cache population in Spring controller

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I want to call all the request mapping method(which has @Resource injection) before the server starts. How I can do this?

```
@Controller
public class ServiceController {
     @Resource(name="userService")
     private IUserService userService;  

     @RequestMapping("/getAllCountry")
     public String getAllCountry() {
        return   userService.getAllCountry();
     }
      @RequestMapping("/getAllStates")
     public String getAllStates() {
        return   userService.getStates();
     } 
      @PostConstruct
      public void cacheData(){
         cache.put("ALL_COUNTRY_DATA", getAllCountry());
         cache.put("ALL_STATE_DATA", getAllStates());
      }
}
```

The above code fails and give me IllegalStateException. What is the best way to call the request mapping methods before the server is up and populate the cache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `ApplicationListener` in conjunction with `ContextRefreshedEvent`:

```
@Controller
public class ServiceController implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {

    private static final Map<String, String> cache = new HashMap<>();

    @Resource(name = "userService")
    private IUserService userService;

    @RequestMapping("/getAllCountry")
    public String getAllCountry() {
        return userService.getAllCountry();
    }

    @RequestMapping("/getAllStates")
    public String getAllStates() {
        return userService.getStates();
    }

    public void cacheData() {
        cache.put("ALL_COUNTRY_DATA", getAllCountry());
        cache.put("ALL_STATE_DATA", getAllStates());
    }

    @Override
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent event) {
        cacheData();
    }
}
```